# Wordpress page won't load from Google referrer, loads fine if I browse to it directly

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-301

I updated my Wordpress site and added a SSL hosting option with GoDaddy.  Whether connected or not, anytime I try to load my site from a Google search result, the site will NOT load.  I need to refresh the page and it will load.  The initial load is giving me a 301 error.

If I bypass Google and simply navigate to my site, I have no problem, the site loads no problem.  I have disabled all plugins on my site and it doesn't eliminate the issue.

Any ideas?  Things I can try?  Please let me know, thanks.

Comment: Hey, having the same issue now. did you find any solution?

Comment: My question was flagged here so had to move it to webmasters, https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137642/googlebot-is-failed-to-crawl-wordpress-site